# Accessing Amazon AWS service from QML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, qml, qt-creator, aws-sdk

I am trying to use AWS SDK (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.30.js) in my Qt-Creator Project with the purpose of uploading an image to my S3 bucket.

I have copy-pasted the JavaScript above to a file named awsSdk.js and did the following in my main.qml file:

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import "jsTest.js" as JsTest
import "awsSdk.js" as AWSSdk

Window {
visible: true
width: 360
height: 360

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "white"
    Text {
        id: txt
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        text: "Counter"
        color: "Blue"

    }
    MouseArea {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (JsTest.x>=20) {
                console.log("Have a nice day :)");
                Qt.quit();
            }
            else
                txt.text = JsTest.jsTest();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I can import the jsTest.js file perfectly. But when I try to do the same for awsSdk.js I get the following error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:8 Script qrc:/awsSdk.js unavailable
qrc:/awsSdk.js:6023 Expected token `identifier'
```

Source Code for jsTest.js:

```
// jsTest.js
var x=0;
function jsTest()
{
    x++;
    return "Counter : "+x+"";
}
```

Have I missed something? Do you have another suggestion for I to upload a file to AWS S3 from a Qt Project using only QML/Javascript?

Comment: I am not familiar with QT nor QML but why copy / paste and to risk to introduce errors?  Can't you save the AWS SDK JS and reference the file from your import statement : import "lib/js/aws-sdk-2.0.30.js" as AWSSDK ?

Comment: Hi @SébastienStormacq, I've tried your suggestion but without success. Still gave me the same errors. Thank's

Comment: I don't know QT/QML enough to help you, sorry.  I would just suggest the following debug approach :  1/ keep in mind that the Browser JS SDK is designed to work in a browser.  I don't know QT execution environment : does it emulate a full browser and provide access to browser's exposed objects ?  2/ Instead of using the minified version of the SDK, use the plain text one, easier to debug (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/tree/master/dist).  Take note of the line number of the error and explore the source code to find possible explanations

Comment: Ok guys, never mind, It's solved now :) For some reason, in qml.qrc was missing the pointer to the file. Added it manually and now it is working. Thanks for the help anyway @SébastienStormacq

Comment: hi im really glad you got this working. I've been needing something like this for so long. Is there any chance of you putting a link to a fully working example up online for us please? that would be a massive help

Comment: Hi @TheMan68, I don't have access to the full code right now, but the content of my qml.qrc file is listed above in my post (updated).

Comment: still a very big help. thank you so much. if i can get something working then i can post a full working project on here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

([Answered by a question edit  - converted to a community wiki.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))

The OP wrote:

> It's solved now. For some reason, in `qml.qrc` was missing the pointer to the file. Added it manually and now it is working.
>
> Content of qml.qrc file:
>
> ```
> <RCC>
>     <qresource prefix="/">
>     <file>main.qml</file>
>     <file>jsTest.js</file>
>     <file>jQuery.js</file>
>     <file>aws-sdk-2.0.30.js</file>
>     </qresource>
> </RCC>
> ```